# How to add flavored resources but not enumerate all the flavors and duplicate resources

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 3 flavor dimensions "foo", "bar", "quax"

I need licence files in my res/raw resource folders. Licences are tied to application packge name. "foo" and "bar" both append suffix to applicationId, so then need separete licences. Lets say each has 2 values, so its 4 licences in total

so I reconed I only needed

- foo1Bar1/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo1Bar2/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo2Bar1/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo2Bar2/res/raw/licence.lic

**But it doesn't work, it only works if I append "quax" values so foo1Bar1Quax1, foo1Bar1Quax2, ...**
Which is obviously very stupid, as it duplicates the licence files across quax flavor folder, which have no effect on the licence what so ever, since quax flavor doesn't change the package name

And I don't want to do that. Android Gradle plugin pls

// Edit
I noticed I only need to declare any value of the quax dimension in the folder name and it works

- foo1Bar1Quax1/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo1Bar2Quax1/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo2Bar1Quax1/res/raw/licence.lic
- foo2Bar2Quax1/res/raw/licence.lic
- 

Which is almost worse, since it implies its when the quax flavor is quax1, **however it works even then its quax2 *facepalm*** which is extremely confusing